# QString to TEXT()

Tags: qt, qt4, registry

I need to make a call like this

```
RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, TEXT("SOFTWARE\\MICROSOFT\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion"), 0, KEY_READ | KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &m_hRegKey)
```

but instead of

```
TEXT("SOFTWARE\\MICROSOFT\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion")
```

i have only a qstring

i already tried

```
QString key = settings.fileName() + settings.group();
RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, key.toStdString().c_str(), 0, KEY_READ | KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &hkey);
```

but i get:

```
x.cpp:97: Fehler: cannot convert 'const char*' to 'LPCWSTR {aka const wchar_t*}' for argument '2' to 'LONG RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY, LPCWSTR, DWORD, REGSAM, PHKEY)'
     RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, key.toStdString().c_str(), 0, KEY_READ | KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &hkey);
```

i need the RegOpenKeyEx because i need to read binary values from the registry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close : QString has a [toStdWString()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toStdWString) function, which returns a `std::wstring` instead of the `std::string` returned by toStdString().

Then, call [c_str()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/basic_string/c_str/) to get a `const wchar_t*`.

Comment: There's no reason to go through `std::wstring`.